# What does "confess" mean in this context?

Tags: lyrics

The first two lines of Nancy Sinatra's song, "[These Boots Are Made for Walkin’](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SbyAZQ45uww)" written by Lee Hazlewood, are the following:

> You keep saying you got something for me
>
> Something you call love but confess

How is "confess" used here. I don't understand the sentence structure, especially because of the "but" used.

Comment: Confess: *tell the truth*..read the following part and you can undestand. You keep saying you got something for me
Something you call love, ***but confess
You've been messing where you shouldn't have been messing***
And now someone else is getting all your best

Comment: @Josh61 Yes, I know what "to confess" means and I did read the lyrics completely several times and yet I don't understand it.

Comment: She is saying that he says he  loves her, but  he has been messing (going with other girls ) instead.

Comment: Never mind. As Pifagor told in his answer, I was expecting that the sentence ends after "confess".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sentence continues "... but confess/ you've been messing..." It's just the pause in the lyrics, caused by the rythm of the song, that confuses you.

Comment: Ahh, now I understand.